# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')

Tags: java, jackson

I am calling the database stored procedure which returns the output as XML.

DB output

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEEID>1</EMPLOYEEID>
  <EMPLOYEENAME>SEAN</EMPLOYEENAME>
  <DEPT>ACOUNTING</DEPT>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEEID>6</EMPLOYEEID>
  <EMPLOYEENAME>KAREN</EMPLOYEENAME>
  <DEPT>HR</DEPT>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I am using Jackson to convert XML String to java objects. I have created a supporting java class to map XML to java objects

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ROWSET")
public class RowSet {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ROW")
    private Row [] row;

    public RowSet() {
    }

    public Row [] getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(Row [] row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
}

class Row {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EMPLOYEEID")
    private String employeeId;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EMPLOYEENAME")
    private String employeeName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DEPT")
    private String dept;

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
}
```

Code to create java object from string xml

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    String ouputput= getEmployeeData();// DB call to get data as xml string
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    RowSet rowSet= xmlMapper.readValue(ouputput, RowSet.class);
    System.out.println(rowSet.getRow().length);
}
```

I am getting the following exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.org.employee.Row no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Row` array in XML is supposed to have a wrapper (apart from `RowSet`) that doesn't exist in you XML text. [Tell Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations#jacksonxmlelementwrapper) to not look for a wrapper e.g.

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ROW")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private Row[] row;
```